# React-Router - Update BrowserHistory without a Refresh of the Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've run into unique problem w/ the react-router - I say unique because I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

**Works Great:**

When a user loads the below react application at the `/` route, they are redirected to the `/locations/random` route which then triggers an API `GET` request in the `shouldComponentUpdate` block. Once the data are retrieved and stored in the `LocationStore` component, there is an event emitted to the `Dashboard` component to render a new row with that retrieved data. All well and good.

**Problem Area:**

After the data are retrieved and stored in the `LocationStore`, I want to grab the `id` property of the data `data.id` and put that value into the current visible url, i.e. `locations/100` and not `locations/random` so a user can navigate back in the future, but when I do `browserHistory.push('locations/100');` it hits the `Router` again and the whole process begins again which means the same data are being retrieved again. Is there a way to update the visible URL and save it in `browserHistory` without triggering the `Router`? Or is there a way to create a new `Route` like `<Route path="/locations/random" hiddenFromHistory=true component={Dashboard}/>`?

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRedirect} from 'react-router'
import {isInteger} from 'lodash'

let _data = {};
let _changeListeners = [];

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRedirect to="/locations/random"/>
            <Route path="/locations/:locationId" component={Dashboard}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));

const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>Home</div>
    }
});

const Dashboard = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: {}
        }
    },

    updateData(){
        // Once the LocationStore has sent out a notification that the data has changed, trigger a render of the dashboard
        this.setState({
            data: LocationStore.getData()
        });
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
        // Trigger a request to load new data when the url changes
        LocationStore.getLocation(nextProps.params);
        return true;
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        LocationStore.addChangeListener(this.updateData);
    },

    componentWillUnmount() {
        LocationStore.removeChangeListener(this.updateData);
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="page-container" style={{ paddingBottom: 20}}>
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Display Data Here as a Row</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

const LocationStore = {

    getLocation: function (params) {
        // Get location by id or random
        const isRandom = !isInteger(params.locationId);
        var url = (isRandom) ? "/api/locations/random" : `/api/locations/${params.locationId}`;
        Utils.getJSON(url, function (err, res) {
            _data = res;

            // If the user hit the random route, update the URL here to show the id of the record brought down
            if (isRandom) {
                const path = `/locations/${_data.id}`;
                browserHistory.push(path);
            }

            LocationStore.notifyChange();
        })
    },

    getData: function () {
        return _data;
    },

    notifyChange: function () {
        _changeListeners.forEach(function (listener) {
            listener()
        })
    },

    addChangeListener: function (listener) {
        _changeListeners.push(listener)
    },

    removeChangeListener: function (listener) {
        _changeListeners = _changeListeners.filter(function (l) {
            return listener !== l
        })
    }
};

const Utils = {
    getJSON: function (url, cb) {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onload = function () {
            if (req.status === 404) {
                cb(new Error('not found'))
            } else {
                cb(null, JSON.parse(req.response))
            }
        };
        req.open('GET', url);
        req.send()
    }
};
```

**Working Update:**

```
/* ./LocationStore */
if (isRandom) {
    _isLoadingRandomLocation = true;
    const path = `/locations/${_data.id}`;
    browserHistory.replace(path)      
}

/* ./Dashboard */
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    // When the URL params change get locations
    if (nextProps.params !== this.props.params) {
        if (LocationStore.getIsLoadingRandomLocation()) {
            LocationStore.setIsLoadingRandomLocation(false);
        }
        else {
            LocationStore.getLocation(nextProps.params);
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `replaceState` here instead `pushState`. `replaceState` is going to replace the history entry with the URL that's been provided, so it will be as though the user never went to your /random URL.

Relevant API: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#replacepathorloc

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: Thanks @michael-camden. That works well and is exactly what I need. Now I need to find a way to trigger a new data update when `this.props.params` changes because `shouldComponentUpdate` seems to trigger too often.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` should be used as a means of preventing updates, not acting on updates. `componentDidUpdate` is the correct lifecycle event. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods